# Implicitly Animated Text Color

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to create an ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget that animates the color of a Text. I'm basing it on [AnimatedPosition](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/26c198c15766eb8b6514426a49f06772585e0535/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart#L1027). This is the code I have so far:

```
class AnimatedText extends ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget {
  const AnimatedText({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    this.icon,
    this.color,
    super.curve,
    required super.duration,
    super.onEnd,
  });

  final String label;
  final Widget? icon;
  final Color? color;

  @override
  ImplicitlyAnimatedWidgetState<AnimatedText> createState() =>
      _AnimatedTextState();
}

class _AnimatedTextState extends ImplicitlyAnimatedWidgetState<AnimatedText> {
  ColorTween? _color;

  @override
  void forEachTween(TweenVisitor<dynamic> visitor) {
    _color = visitor(_color, widget.color,
        (dynamic value) => ColorTween(begin: value as Color)) as ColorTween?;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_color!.evaluate(animation)!.value.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(color: _color!.evaluate(animation)));
  }
}
```

And this is where I'm trying to use it. When I press the button it doesn't look like anything is happening but if I press it again the text rebuilds and jumps to the correct color for that time in the animation. But it only updates when I press the button.

```
class AnimationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnimationPage> createState() => _AnimationPageState();
}

class _AnimationPageState extends State<AnimationPage> {
  final _colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.blue,
  ];

  int _selected = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color color = _colors[_selected];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            AnimatedText(
              label: "ANIMATION",
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
              color: color,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selected = (_selected + 1) % 2;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text("Press"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```